# How to avoid duplicate subviews in an iOS / Swift tableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `tableView` that displays chat messages. I want to insert a date separator before every message that is the first message of a new date (day). So, I create a `label` and add it to the chat message view and adjust the constraints. But my method is redrawing the `label` view that I insert:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Chat Message", for: indexPath) as! ChatViewCellView

   cell.myChatView.Text = self.messageData[self.messageIndex!].messages[indexPath.item]

   let dateLabel:UILabel = createDateSep(date: self.messageData[self.messageIndex!].message_dates[indexPath.item])

   cell.myChatView.addSubview(dateLabel)

   let labelConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.myChatViewReceived.nameView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: dateLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 18)

   labelConstraint.identifier = "dateSeparatorIdentifier"
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([labelConstraint])
}
```

(`createDateSep` is just my function to format a date string.)

The service that feeds the tableView provides two arrays, one with the text `messages` and one with the dates( `message_dates`).

I understand conceptually why the view is recreated during scrolling, but it's taking different date values out of the array that holds the dates and drawing them in the same spot. I don't know why that's happening, and I don't know how to prevent the redraw even if the date strings were all the same, correct values. Any solution must be compatible with iOS 9. I do have separate Xibs

Here's what it looks like (notice there is a Nov 22 and a Dec 26 date, and Dec 26 is correct):

[image]

Comment: I dont have time to give an in depth answer, but take a look at this video, it should lead you in the right direction: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5opi9tIuro

Comment: Cells are ***reused*** (as indicated by `dequeueReusableCell`). You should not add subviews inside `cellForRowAt` because another one will be added every time the cell is reused. Design your cell with the `dateLabel` already there to begin with, and set its text. If it only needs to be visible on certain cells, then set its `.isHidden` property to true or false as needed.

Comment: @DonMag Was hoping to avoid putting the date label in the design because there are two separate nibs, one for message received, one for sent. So the date label will be duplicated and there will be additional constraint code required for show/hide. But I will do this if not better solution exists.

Comment: Duplicating the date label in two nibs is trivial, so that should not be an issue. To make the constraints easier, put the elements in a Stack View. When you set the date label to hidden, that vertical space will be automatically collapsed.

Comment: @DonMag Better to do the duplicate label, or a new nib for the date separator and then plug extra data into the arrays?

Comment: @lilbiscuit - Is there a reason you are using separate nibs? Unless there are additional elements you haven't shown, you have a very simple cell layout. You could easily do it via code only, or via prototype cells... you could use a "base" cell class and subclass it for "received" or "sent" chat message types to save even more effort / duplications.

Comment: @DonMag existing code is the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: Cells are reused, which means you are adding ***another*** "Date Separator Label" each time.

My suggestion is to:

- add the "Date Separator Label" to both of your "Received" and "Sent" XIBs.
- Add two constraints from the top of the "Name / Time" label -- one to the bottom of the "Date Separator Label" and one to the top of the content view.
- Connect them via `IBOutlet` in your cell classes. Name one `dateVisibleConstraint` and the other `dateHiddenConstraint`
- Set the Priority of the `dateVisibleConstraint` to `High (750)`, and set the Priority of the `dateHiddenConstraint` to `Low (250)`
- At run-time, adjust the Priority values based on whether the date label is hidden or showing.

I posted a complete example here: https://github.com/DonMag/ChatLayout

Output:

[image]

and, after some scrolling:

[image]